# Is there any benefit to create a custom View if I am using RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, android-viewholder

**Background:**

I learned coding and Android for about half an year now. Recently I start to make better codes by implementing custom Views, so that it sticks better to MVC pattern. But when it comes to RecyclerView with ViewHolder, I am a bit confused.

**Scenario:**

Let's say I have a `RecyclerView` with a `ViewHolder` just like everyone else do in Android app nowadays. I have created xml for each item.

**Problem:**

When I am thinking whether to create a custom `View` for the item inside or not, I found it seems to be unncessary, because `ViewHolder` itself is already a class, and I can put the View related codes in `ViewHolder` instead.
If I implement a custom `View`, the `ViewHolder` will just be an almost empty container where its only responsibility is to pass the data object to the `View` object.

Now, **suppose the item View will not be used anywhere else except RecyclerView**, is there still any benefit to implement a custom `View` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no benefit for creating a custom view if it's only going to be used by a single recycler view in a single place in the whole app. The main reason for creating custom views is to build reusable components throughout your app.

Comment: `The main reason for creating custom views is to build reusable components throughout your app.` IMO custom view are created because your current view framework does not provide the necessary functionality for your usecase. It is also the main reason why people use libraries.

Comment: @Enzokie Not all of the time. Another case is when you find you have a lot of similar patterned views in your project, you really should create a custom view that combines different view elements, and put the UI update logic inside that View class.

Comment: @SiraLam just what I said `if your current view framework does not provide the necessary functionality for your usecase` then you create a custom view, that example you said earlier qualifies to that statement.